# Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I have to check if a linkedlist is in another. Here i want to know if L2 is in L1 but I get this error     **if c.suiv!=None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'suiv'** and I can't solve it.

Here is my code

```
class Cellule(object):
def __init__(self, entier):
    self.entier=entier
    self.suiv=None

L1=Cellule(5)
L1.suiv=Cellule(2)
L1.suiv.suiv=Cellule(1)
L1.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(2)
L1.suiv.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(3)
L1.suiv.suiv.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(4)
L1.suiv.suiv.suiv.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(4)


L2=Cellule(1)
L2.suiv=Cellule(2)
L2.suiv.suiv=Cellule(3)

p=L1


while p!=None:
    a=Cellule(0)
    b=a
    c=p.suiv
    for j in range(3):
        if c.suiv!=None:
            b.suiv=Cellule(c.entier)
            b=b.suiv
            c=c.suiv
        a=a.suiv
        if a==L2:
            print("good")
    p=p.suiv
```

Thanks for your help, if you also know a good tutorial on linked list, i'll take it !

Comment: just test against `if c:`

Comment: The problem is that your outer loop is testing for the end, but your inner loop isn’t. So when the outer loop gets close to the end, the inner loop reaches the end and you get the error. Solution: do more checking.

Comment: The comparison algorithm presents a lot of misunderstandings: creating new `Cellule` node, using a for-loop with a fixed range and comparison as `if a==L2:` will be always `False` because `a=Cellule(0)` !!!